# Why nextjs useEffect triggered every time i route

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a `useEffect` function in the `Layout` component which fetch my `userData` and store it in `redux-store` but it is triggered with every   **route changes**.

I want the `useFffect` function to run the first time and don't trigger again when I change my routes. This is not right with sending more useless requests to the server. How can I do that?

This is my `Layout` component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "../navbar/navbar";
import Footer from "../footer/footer";
import Head from "next/head";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";
import { getUserData } from "../../redux/actions/Auth";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const [cookie, setCookie] = useCookies(["token"]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => { // this useEffect triggers every time i route !! 
    const { token } = cookie;
    if (token) {
      axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      dispatch({ type: "IS_LOGGED_IN" });
      dispatch(getUserData(token));
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="layout" dir="rtl">
      <Head>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link
          rel="preconnect"
          href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"
          crossOrigin="true"
        />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Kufi+Arabic:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          charset="UTF-8"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css"
        />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css"
        />
      </Head>
      <Navbar />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 1):

##### The Problem:

You are using the `useEffect` hook which triggered on component did mount, also will trigger with every route change that's the default and **correct** behavior of `useEffect` hook since you use it on `Layout` component and it will re-render with every route changes.

##### The Solutions:

There are some solutions to handle these cases like implementing `getUserData(token)` on a parent component of `Layer` component which does not get re-render on every route change.

Another solution is to use another state variable to hold the API call status. you have an `IS_LOGGED_IN` action which may change your reducer like this:

```
case IS_LOGGED_IN:
  return {
    ...state,
    isUserLoggedIn: true
  }
```

So, you need to get and check this *sample property* on `useEffect` before dispatching the `getUserData`:

```
const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.user.isUserLoggedIn) // get isUserLoggedIn from the state

useEffect(() => { 
    if (!isLoggedIn) {  // -----> getUserData if user is not logged in

      const {token} = cookie;     
      if (token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        dispatch({ type: "IS_LOGGED_IN" });
        dispatch(getUserData(token));
      }
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn]);
```

##### Explanation:

once you use the `Layout` component, the `isLoggedIn` value is false (since the user is not logged in) so the `dispatch(getUserData(token))` method will call and get the data. after that, the `isLoggedIn` will change to `true` so the conditional statement in the `useEffect` check it and doesn't let to dispatching `getUserData` again.

**Note:** You may need another action with the proper procedure on `reducer` to toggle between the user is logged in or logged out on the application.